# cannot find -lfcl using fcl library

Tags: cmake, package, ros, fcl

I want to run a ROS node using fcl library. I just wrote a small code and I edited the CMakeLists.txt to make sure that I can run the node but I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfcl
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?

My CMakeLists.txt is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(package_name)

find_path(FCL_INCLUDE_DIRS
NAMES fcl/collision.h
HINTS ${PC_FCL_INCLUDEDIR}
PATHS "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include")

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    nav_msgs
    roscpp
    sensor_msgs
    visualization_msgs
    tf
    dynamic_reconfigure
    message_generation
    laser_geometry
    geometry_msgs
    cmake_modules
)

find_package(Boost REQUIRED)
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(PCL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(fcl REQUIRED)


generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
)


generate_messages(
    DEPENDENCIES
    geometry_msgs sensor_msgs nav_msgs visualization_msgs  
)


catkin_package(
    INCLUDE_DIRS include
    LIBRARIES ${haptic_teleoperation}
    CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime nav_msgs roscpp sensor_msgs 
    DEPENDS eigen
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files  
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(include
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Eigen_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${FCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)


## Declare a cpp library
add_library()

add_executable(fcl_test src/fcl_test.cpp)
add_dependencies(fcl_test
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg        
    ${PROJECT_NAME}_generate_messages_cpp
)
target_link_libraries(fcl_test
    fcl
    ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
    ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
    ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: Please add your CMakeLists.txt to the question, so we can see if the problem is somewhere inside it.

Comment: @luator I edited the question by adding my Cmakelist file. Also, I have a question do i have to add any thing in the package.xml file ?

Comment: No, as FCL is a external library and not a ROS package, you don't have to add in in `package.xml`.

Comment: @luator it is not necessary but I would say [it is recommended](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep/Tutorials/How%20to%20add%20a%20system%20dependency) to include it in the package.xml so that rosdep can resolve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `fcl` by `${fcl_LIBRARIES}` in the link-command:

```
target_link_libraries(fcl_test
  ${fcl_LIBRARIES}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

If `find_package(fcl REQUIRED)` works correctly, this variable should be automatically set.

Comment: In fact, in the CMakeLists.txt I do not need the `find_path` command (this is something `Find<Pkg>.cmake` module usually does).